# Using array instead of set<string>

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This is a function for finding all Longest common sequence for X and Y sequence.
But this program is in c++ but I want to write it in C.

Is there any way to use array instead of the set?

For eg. if input is

`X = < A, A, T, C, C, >`

`Y = < A, C, A, C, G, >`

then the output should be

`< A, C, C, >`

`< A, A, C, >`

m and n are size of sequence X and Y respectively.

```
/* source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-longest-common-subsequence-set-2-printing/ */

/* Returns set containing all LCS for X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-1] */
set<string> findLCS(string X, string Y, int m, int n) 
{ 
    // construct a set to store possible LCS 
    set<string> s; 

    // If we reaches end of either string, return 
    // a empty set 
    if (m == 0 || n == 0) 
    { 
        s.insert(""); 
        return s; 
    } 

    // If the last characters of X and Y are same 
    if (X[m - 1] == Y[n - 1]) 
    { 
        // recurse for X[0..m-2] and Y[0..n-2] in 
        // the matrix 
        set<string> tmp = findLCS(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1); 

        // append current character to all possible LCS 
        // of substring X[0..m-2] and Y[0..n-2]. 
        for (string str : tmp) 
            s.insert(str + X[m - 1]); 
    } 

    // If the last characters of X and Y are not same 
    else
    { 
        // If LCS can be constructed from top side of 
        // the matrix, recurse for X[0..m-2] and Y[0..n-1] 
        if (L[m - 1][n] >= L[m][n - 1]) 
            s = findLCS(X, Y, m - 1, n); 

        // If LCS can be constructed from left side of 
        // the matrix, recurse for X[0..m-1] and Y[0..n-2] 
        if (L[m][n - 1] >= L[m - 1][n]) 
        { 
            set<string> tmp = findLCS(X, Y, m, n - 1); 

            // merge two sets if L[m-1][n] == L[m][n-1] 
            // Note s will be empty if L[m-1][n] != L[m][n-1] 
            s.insert(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()); 
        } 
    } 
     return s; 
}
```

Comment: You could write your own set for C. AFAIK a set is some kind of a tree.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I would love to :( Thanks. Can you give me a hint on how to perform insert in the form of array?

Comment: Do you really need a set or could you use an unordered_set? A set is usually implemented as [red-black-tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). An unordered_set is usually implemented as some kind of hash map.

Comment: @ThomasSablik unordered is fine too, I think.

Comment: Create a struct `node` containing `key` and `next`. Create an array of pointers to `node`s. Init all elements with `NULL`. Create a hash function that creates a integer of a string. The elements in the array are the buckets. Each bucket contains a linked list with elements. The size of the array is the number of buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a self-made C unordered_set using arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Buckets 1000

struct Node {
    char *key;
    struct Node *next;
};

void initNode(struct Node **node, const char *str) {
    *node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    size_t l = strlen(str);
    (*node)->key = (char *) malloc(l * sizeof(char));
    strncpy((*node)->key, str, l);
    (*node)->next = NULL;
}

void freeNode(struct Node *node) {
    if (node->next) {
        freeNode(node->next);
    }
    free(node->key);
    free(node);
}

struct Set {
    struct Node *buckets[Buckets];
};

void initSet(struct Set *set) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Buckets; ++i) {
        set->buckets[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void freeSet(struct Set *set) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Buckets; ++i) {
        if (set->buckets[i]) {
            free(set->buckets[i]);
        }
    }
}

unsigned int hash(const char *str) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (; *str; ++str) {
        sum += *str;
    }
    return sum % Buckets;
}

int insert(struct Set *set, const char *str) {
    const unsigned int h = hash(str);
    if (!set->buckets[h]) {
        initNode(&set->buckets[h], str);
        return 1;
    }

    struct Node *node = set->buckets[h];
    while (node->next && strcmp(str, node->key)) node = node->next;
    if (!strcmp(str, node->key)) return 0;
    initNode(&node->next, str);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    struct Set set;
    initSet(&set);
    printf("%d", insert(&set, "Text"));
    printf("%d", insert(&set, "Text2"));
    printf("%d", insert(&set, "Text"));
    freeSet(&set);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will help me a lot to write my program!! Just one question, how to perform insert in this kind of situation? s.insert(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());  where we have to insert all the elements in the range [position1, last)  in another set container.

Comment: There are no classes and no methods in C. Therefore I wrote a function `insert`. You can add a modified function that takes two pointer and inserts all elements.